# Terminate IF block in Transact-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

This is probably quite a rookie question, but I can't find in the MSDN examples online of how to end an IF/ELSE block in Transact-SQL. For example, I want to create a SP that does this:

```
USE [MyDb];
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON;
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON;
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_MyStoredProc]
@param1 DATE, @param2 INT, @param3 BIT, @param4 [dbo].[CustomDataType] READONLY
WITH EXEC AS CALLER
AS
-- Only run this part if @param3 == true
IF (@param3 = 1)
   BEGIN
     --do stuff...
   END
-- I don't really need an else here, as I'm simply doing an 
-- extra step at the beginning if my param tells me to

-- I always want this next part to run...
-- do more stuff...
GO
```

I have a solution that I think works (posted as answer below), but I feel like I'm working around my lack of knowledge instead of doing the best pattern.

Edit- I deleted my first solution as it was a horrible idea and didn't want others to try implementing that. Turns out the question was actually the solution in this case; thanks to all.

Comment: Have you tested the code you have in the question? Does it not work? In T-SQL, `if` doesn't need an `else`

Comment: Interestingly, I haven't tested that specifically... my boss sent me a snippet that wouldn't compile, so I removed the offending part (he had an END after the IF that threw things off). So does the BEGIN/END effectively terminate the IF statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't have to be an else statement. Whatever's between the BEGIN/END will be run if it meets the IF condition and then your SQL will progress normally after that. It's the same thing as:

```
If (x == 1) {
   // condition met, do stuff
}
// do more stuff
```

You were really close. Just needed some tweaking.

```
IF (@param3 = 1)
  BEGIN
  -- do stuff if a param tells me to (has to be done before main block of code is ran below)
  END    
-- do stuff that should always be ran.
GO
```

Do yourself and your team a favor: never use a goto unless it's 100% necessary. Usually, they are not necessary with well-structured code.

Comment: Thanks; I 100% agree with the GOTO comment, hence why I figured I was going down the wrong route there. Funny, but I figured out that the BEGIN and END were essentially the C# curly braces right when your answer popped up, so I actually had the solution correct in the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for the `IF` statement is

```
IF Boolean_expression 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } 
[ ELSE 
     { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
```

The `ELSE` part is optional.

A "sql_statement" is any single statement. A "statement_block" is a group of statements wrapped in a `BEGIN` and `END`

More details:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx

Comment: Thanks; I saw that entry and understand the form, but what I'm not understanding 100% is what 'ends' that block (e.g. in C#, I know it's ended by '}', or in Python it's controlled by line spacing). None of the examples (that I could find anyway) show code that should execute after the IF/ELSE, hence why I'm not sure if my code that should always run will actually run.